# Hiding implementation details of base class from derived class

Tags: c++, constructor

Say that we have a base A class and a derived B class:

```
struct A
{
    A(int a) : a(a) {}
    int a;
};

struct B : public A
{
    B(int a, int b) : A(a), b(b) {}
    int b;
};
```

Is there any way to define the B class without knowing the A class' constructor? For instance a factory class may be responsible
for providing the data that the A class needs but the writter of the B class doesn't have to know anything about it.
Basically assuming that we don't delegate the constructors is it possible to first initialize the A class part of an object and then initialize the B part using another set of constructor arguments?

Comment: This doesn't seem right, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: Can you pass the factory to A's constructor, so A can get the data itself?

Comment: every inherited class will have to initialize the base class constructor. that will work when you will pass data to A class from B class constructor. all the constructor arguments need to be passed in the same constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a variadic templated constructor that can forward its arguments to the base class <sup>[1]</sup>

```
struct B : public A
{
    template<typename...Ts>
    B(int b, Ts&&...args) : A(std::forward<Ts>(args)...), b(b) 
    {
    }
    int b;
};
```

But the above would not be any of any practical use unless <sup>[2]</sup> the base class was itself a generic aspect, eg

```
template<typename Base>
struct B : public Base
{
    template<typename...Ts>
    B(int b, Ts&&...args) : Base(std::forward<Ts>(args)...), b(b) 
    { 
        // above the initialization of b (its related argument)
        // are not part of the variadic pack
    }
    int b;
};
```

[**Example**](http://ideone.com/9IrwSc)

---

<sup>1. The above would imply that a related factory method also uses variadic templates</sup>

<sup>2. Considering just a class that wants to construct its base without knowing how many or what type of variables it's constructed from. Uses may vary depending on context</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A derived class needs to see the full definition of it's base class, so no, you can't define B without A's definition (which involves it's constructors).

You need to check, if you really need inheritance here. If you don't, then A and B can be separate classes (so B isn't a derived class of A), and you can construct them separately. Then e.g. you can create a third class which has members of A and B.

Answer (score 0):

You can't inherit from incomplete type. If you just forward declare the base class you will get a compile-time error. For example, in `gcc` (I have 4.8.1) you will get a `invalid use of incomplete type` error. So, you can't hide class declaration if that class is going to be the base class.